# C# Index was outside the bounds of the array [combobox]

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

Below is the code that is resulting in error when I start debug. I receive a message pop up when I chose on the option from combobox1 or combobox2: Index was outside the bounds of the array. How could I solve this?

Thanks for your time reading. :)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    String[] arr1 = new String[2];

    arr1[0] = "SG";
    arr1[1] = "MY";

    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(arr1);
    comboBox2.Items.AddRange(arr1);        
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[,] arr = new double[2, 2];

    for(int i = 0; i <2; i++)
    {            
        arr[0, 0] = 1;
        arr[0, 1] = 1.24;
        arr[1, 0] = 0.80;
        arr[1, 1] = 1;
        label1.Text = 
            arr[comboBox1.SelectedIndex,
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString();//Index was outside the bounds of the array.         
    }
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    double[,] arr = new double[2, 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        arr[0, 0] = 1;
        arr[0, 1] = 1.24;
        arr[1, 0] = 0.80;
        arr[1, 1] = 1;
        label1.Text = 
            arr[comboBox1.SelectedIndex,
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString();//Index was outside the bounds of the array.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is anything else changing what is in comboBox1 or comboBox2? What are the selectedindex values at the time the error occurs?

Comment: "A value of negative one (-1) is returned if no item is selected." Possibly?

Comment: SelectedIndex is default -1 if no item is selected in the Combobox.

Answer (score 7):

You should step through it in debug mode. But I imagine it's because one of your ComboBoxes doesn't have a selected value, therefore `SelectedIndex` is returning `-1`, which is invalid.

You could add a validation check at the start of each event to see if both ComboBoxes have selected values. Or better still, use a common function:

```
void CreateArray()
{
    //could also validate the values are not greater than 1 if you think that is worth it
    if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    double[,] arr = new double[2, 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        arr[0, 0] = 1;
        arr[0, 1] = 1.24;
        arr[1, 0] = 0.80;
        arr[1, 1] = 1;
        label1.Text = arr[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, comboBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString();//Index was outside the bounds of the array.
    }

}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateArray();
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateArray();
}

//or subscribe both events to the same handler
```

In this case, `label1` will only be populated once bot ComboBox values have been set. Alternative, you could also set each ComboBox to have a default value first. Depends what your requirements are really.

---

A couple of other notes:

- Your `for loop` appears to be useless. You are just doing the exact same thing twice!
- It is better to create the array once, rather than on each event. Create a class level variable to hold the array (this is actually demonstrated in Sayse's answer)

Comment: You seem to have updated your answer at same time as me writing mine.. sorry if it looks like I copied!

Comment: Thanks for the method and your notes. I will keep in mind. :)

Answer (score 3):

this is partly an off topic answer but please consider the following..

```
private double[,] arr = new double[2,2]{{1,1.24},{0.80, 1}};

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;
     label1.Text = arr[comboBox1.SelectedIndex, comboBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString();
}
```

You can even use this event for both comboboxes

Answer (score 2):

When there's nothing selected in a `ComboBox`, its `SelectedIndex` may become -1. I suggest you first check if `SelectedIndex` is not -1 first, or normalize it so that if it is -1 treat it as 0.